# How to Draw BoundingBox or Tag Objects Which Has Less Area Than Others

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, tags, bounding-box

In my image I have 5 Objects in black-white form. Some are respectively small, some are bigger. 
So what i am trying to do is drawing a BoundingBox or tag the objects which has less area than others (ex. under 10pixels/area)  .

I couldn't make this happen, can anyone help?

Comment: Have you spent time in investigating [regionprops](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html). I could give you answer in a minute but you have to show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

That's two separate problems. The first is to select only objects above a certain area. So simply remove all objects below it:

```
clean = bwareaopen (im, 10); # remove all objects with area below 10
```

Then for the second problem there are many possibilities. You can get their borders:

```
borders = bwperim (clean);
imshow (borders);
```

You can label them:

```
labeled = bwlabel (clean);
imshow (labeled);
```

Or you can get their bounding box (which depending on the shape of your objects may overlap):

```
props = regionprops (clean, 'BoundingBox');
all_bb = props.BoundingBox;
boxes = false (size (clean));
for i = 1:numel (all_bb)
    bb = all_bb{i};
    bb(round (bb(2):bb(2)+bb(4), bb(1):bb(1)+bb(3))) = true;
end
imshow (boxes);
```

Note: this was written out of my head, no testing.  There may be small oversights, but nothing major.